# htaccess sitemap.xml rewrite to /sitemaps/$_SERVER["MYVAR"]/sitemap.xml

Tags: htaccess, apache

I am trying to update htaccess to write as following:

htaccess sitemap.xml rewrite to `/sitemaps/$_SERVER["MYVAR"]/sitemap.xml`

This rewrite should only occur if sitemap.xml is requested in root (otherwise the above would loop)

I came up with this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sitemap.xml
RewriteRule .* /sitemaps/$_SERVER["MYVAR"]/sitemap.xml [L,NC]
```

But this is not working, server error. Anyone know how to do this?

---

And on a side note: rewrite to `/sitemaps/domain/sitemap.xml` would be fine too
(where domain is captured from the request host either `www.domain.com` or `domain.com`)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a PHP superglobal eg. `$_SERVER["MYVAR"]` in an htaccess expression. (Apache .htaccess files are processed before PHP gets a go, but anyway `$_SERVER["MYVAR"]` is PHP syntax not Apache mod_rewrite syntax). However, depending on what `MYVAR` contains, there might be an alternative.

> This rewrite should only occur if sitemap.xml is requested

Your current `RewriteCond` directive actually does the complete opposite and results in a rewrite when "sitemap.xml" is **not** requested. The `!` prefix negates the regex.

> rewrite to `/sitemaps/domain/sitemap.xml` would be fine too (where `domain` is captured from the request host either `www.domain.com` or `domain.com`)

This is possible, something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %(HTTP_HOST) (www\.)?([a-z0-9-]+)\.com
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml /sitemaps/%2/sitemap.xml [L,NC]
```

Where `%2` is the 2nd parenthesised sub pattern in the `RewriteCond` directive. However, before this you should already have your canonical `www` or `non-www` redirect, so you should already know whether `HTTP_HOST` contains the `www` subdomain or not - this will simplify your `RewriteCond` pattern.